# Stop VLC playback when Windows is idle

Tags: windows-7, vlc-media-player

I listen to internet radio at work on Windows 7, but it uses quite a bit of bandwidth. So I want VLC to stop playback when I'm not using my PC, and resume when I return.

How do I make VLC stop playback when my PC is idle, and play when I'm using it again?

Comment: Sometimes the simplest solutions are the best. I didn't even think of that. Brain fart. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What decides your computer is idle? When you're reading information on screen, is that not considered idle (in regards to your computer)? This may complicate what you want, or you'll have to keep moving the mouse or similar.

To answer you though, I think what you're after is to simply make your PC sleep when it is idle. When the computer sleeps, it should stop the streaming!

> Control Panel -> Power Options -> Change plan settings -> choose the amount of time you desire